# 'getPastEvents' not respond

Tags: reactjs

interactions.js

```
export const loadAllOrders = async (exchange, dispatch) => {
  // Fetch cancelled orders with the "Cancel" event stream
  const cancelStream = await exchange.getPastEvents('Cancel', { fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest' })
  console.log(cancelStream)
}
```

but error like this 
[image]

i don't know what is problem

if you know please help

i m sorry plus Content.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { exchangeSelector } from '../store/selectors'
import { loadAllOrders } from '../store/interactions'

class Content extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.loadBlockchainData(this.props.dispatch)
  }

  async loadBlockchainData(dispatch) {
    await loadAllOrders(this.props.exchange, dispatch)
  }
 ~~~

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    exchange: state.exchangeSelector
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Content)
```

plus new code

Comment: Where you call `loadAllOrders ` ? when you call `loadAllOrders `, param `exchange` that you pass into this function `undefined`

Comment: oh sorry plus new code please see this comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cannot read property 'getPastEvents' of undefined. This mean `exchange` was `undefined` when you call function `loadAllOrders`.

```
async loadBlockchainData(dispatch) {
    await loadAllOrders(this.props.exchange, dispatch)
    // You can not direct access to this.props with function in Class
    // this.props just direct shaft access only in life cycle and render
}
```

So, you must be pass argument into `loadBlockchainData` like this:

```
async loadBlockchainData(exchange, dispatch) {
    await loadAllOrders(exchange, dispatch)
}
```

Call this function in render:

```
this.loadBlockchainData(this.props.exchange)
```

Comment: Hi reviewed your advice last time.
But I looked at the other parts of the code and decided that I defined the exchange part well.
If you have time, would you please take another look at my question?                                    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58395559/getpastevents-undefinedre

Answer (score 0):

probably you already solved it or gave up on it, ;)
But for future readers, check your selectors file and make sure your exchangeSelector looks like this:

```
const exchange = state => get(state, 'exchange.contract')
export const exchangeSelector = createSelector(exchange, e => e)
```

I forgot to put get, which did resolve in undefined for exchange....